# Python regex: include an entire field

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long string *S*, containing several substrings in the format:

```
[&FULL="583 - node#597 <...a lot more characters inside...> ,REALNAME="node#638"]
```

That is:

- It starts with `[&FULL="<a number with 1 to 3 digits>`
- It ends with `REALNAME="node#<a number with 1 to 3 digits>"]`
- And has a lot of characters in the middle, including some special characters and whitespace.

My objective is:

- Get a regex that can grab *all* such substrings
- Extract just the number after `[&FULL=`. Let's call these numbers `x[i]`, for substring *i*.
- Replace the substring *i* with *x[i]*.

As you can imagine, steps 2 and 3 are easy. My partial solution is:

```
r'\[&FULL=[\s\S]*?(?=REALNAME="node#\d{1,3}"\])'
```

- `\[&FULL=` matches the starting portion of the substring
- `[\s\S]*` matches anything in the middle of the substring
- `?(?=REALNAME="node#\d{1,3}"\])` will match the tail end of the substring, but this is where the problem lies.

The portion at the back using `(?=...)` does *not* return `REALNAME="node#638"]` in its result, because, well, that's just not how it behaves. But I'd like to keep that tail end of the string, so that I can use the `replace()` function.

**Edit: Current Solution**

```
# Matches *almost* everything, except for the bit at the back
# places the matches in a list
pattern1 = r'\[&FULL=[\s\S]*?(?=REALNAME="node#\d{1,3}"\])'
pattern1_ls = re.findall(pattern1, my_long_string)

# Pattern to match just the back: 'REALNAME=...'
pattern2 = r'REALNAME="node#\d{1,3}"\]'
realnames_ls = re.findall(pattern2, my_long_string)

# regex to extract NUMBER from each pattern1 result
pattern = r'\[&FULL="\d{1,3}'
for i in range(len(pattern1_ls)):
    # there should be only 1 result
    result=re.findall(pattern, pattern1_ls[i])[0]
    # ditch the first 8 characters, '[&FULL="'
    node_num = result[8:]
    original_pattern = pattern1_ls[i] 
    pattern1_ls[i] = [original_pattern, node_num]

# Replace pattern1 with [&branch_num=NUMBER]
for nd in pattern1_ls:
    my_long_string = my_long_string.replace(nd[0], nd[1])

# Replace pattern2 with empty string (i.e. delete it)
for nm in realnames_ls:
    my_long_string = my_long_string.replace(nm, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you just use groups, like this:

```
\[&FULL=[\s\S]*?(?P<string>REALNAME="node#\d{1,3}"\])
```

Here is the link to an example: https://regex101.com/r/SFiS1G/1

Comment: Answer works to match the given substring; will not work for finding all such substrings of the specified format in my original string S.

Comment: Can you post an example of your text file? A bigger one, so we can test the regex on it...